# Definition of Lebesgue Integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Based on page 314 of Rudin. Let $f$ be measurable and $E\in \mathfrak{M}$. We express $$\int_E f d\mu = \int_E f^+ d\mu-\int_E f^- d\mu  .$$ We say $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and write $f\in L(E,\mu)$ if both $\int_E f^+ d\mu$ and $\int_E f^- d\mu $ are finite.

I wonder if I have strictly follow this definition. If I have $f$ measurable and $\int_E f d\mu < \infty$, then can I immediately conclude that $f\in L(E,\mu)$? For example, if I can express $\int_E f d\mu$ as a summation of terms (not necessarily $\int_E f^+ d\mu$ and $\int_E f^- d\mu$) that are all finite, can I say  $f\in L(E,\mu)$?

Comment: The reason we require handling positive and negative parts separately is related to the fact that a sum of a countably infinite set of real numbers with mixed signs can depend on the order of summation...

Comment: $\int_E fd\mu<\infty$ does not stop the integral from being undefined or equal to $-\infty$.

Comment: You should also bear in mind that $\int_E f d\mu$ is only defined if $f \in L(E,\mu)$. Or, to say it differently: How do you define $\int_E f d\mu$ if you do not know $f \in L(E,\mu)$ already?

Comment: @gerw Actually according to Rudin page 315,  if $\int_E f d\mu$ is $\infty$ or $-\infty$, then the integral of $f$ over $E$ is defined, although $f$ is not integrable. And $f$ is integrable on E only if its integral over E is finite..

Comment: $f \in L(E, \mu)$ if and only if $\int_E |f|\,d\mu < \infty$. But in general, $\int_E f \,d\mu < \infty$ does not imply $\int_E |f|\,d\mu < \infty$ because cancellation can occur if $f$ changes sign.